# Starting JHipster generated app on a Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, jndi, jhipster, tomcat8

I made web application using JHipster. Everything working correctly but when I move it to tomcat/webapps and deploy it I have some errors. After errors, my app runs correctly, so I wasn't focused on this earlier... But now when I'm trying to deploy it on linux server my app starts with several errors "CreateBeanException". I think that this errors appears because I ignored(in windows and linux) tomcat configuration in his files. Can anybody help me with it ? 
I'm using mysql on production.

Here is the log from tomcat.exe
https://pastebin.com/LA12tiL9

Here is my context.xml from tomcat/conf

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
</Context>
```

What I should paste yet? 
I have default configs after install it on windows and linux.
I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have any special need that want to deploy it on a tomcat?
Because

> `JHipster` is a fully Open Source, widely used application generator. Easily create high-quality **Spring Boot** + Angular projects!

And **Spring Boot** gives you an **Embedded Web Server** that you can use out of the box.

So you can easy use the Embedded web-servers that JHipster -> Spring Boot: provides following JHipster steps:

**Generating a WAR file**

```
To package the application as a “production” WAR, type:

./mvnw -Pprod package

Or when using Gradle:

./gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage

This will generate two files (if your application is called “jhipster”):

target/jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
target/jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.original
```

**Executing the WAR file without an application server**

```
Instead of deploying to an application server, many people find it easier to just have an exectuable WAR file.

The first WAR file generated in the previous step is such a WAR, so you can run it in “production” mode by typing (on Mac OS X or Linux):

./jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

If you are on Windows, use:

java -jar jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

For more information please follow this great document by [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/production/)

Comment: Hi @Edmond. Is it possible after machine restart  this ./jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war keeps running ? Or in that case I have to use Tomcat?

Comment: @InêsGomes this looks like a new question and it's something quit standard. To have a java app start after server startup. Depending on what you'r using this is simple possible.

Comment: Thanks @Edmond. Something like this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-app-as-a-service?

Comment: Yes @InêsGomes. That is a good example of startup script for a java app.